# Play 2 doesn't call provided action method in Global's onRequest

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to call different action methods depending on something I put in the session earlier. For this I override the onRequest method in Global like it's recommended in [Play's tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.3/JavaInterceptors). I use Java reflection to construct a new method with the same name and parameters but in a different class B. Class B and and the original class with the original actionMethod implement the same interface. So there shouldn't be a problem.

My onRequest in Global looks like:

```
@Override
public Action onRequest(Request request, final Method actionMethod) {
    if (checkSomething) {
        return super.onRequest(request, getNewActionMethod(actionMethod));
    }
    return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
}

private Method getNewActionMethod(Method oldActionMethod) {
    String name = oldActionMethod.getName();
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = oldActionMethod.getParameterTypes();
    Method newActionMethod = null;
    try {
        newActionMethod = B.class.getMethod(name, parameterTypes);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newActionMethod;
}
```

The Problem here is that Play just ignores my new action method and keeps insisting to call the old one. Am I missing something?

I'm using Play framework 2.2.3.

Comment: Have you put debug to be sure the `onRequest` is called? Are you on the same case as https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3004 ?

Comment: Hi applicius! Yes, I debugged and onRequest is called. It's not the issue you mentioned.